# how to remove white space above footer in homepage, fine with other pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[homepage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJoGb.jpg)

[here is my website, vision and divisions page footers are working fine except homepage](http://thebluegroup.qa/)

Comment: Wecome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The way you wrote your question, it is unclear what you are asking and what you have tried to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line in your file static.css

http://www.thebluegroup.qa/wp-content/themes/thebluegroup/css/static.css

it's caused by "top:-610px";

```
.news-wrapper{ position:relative; top:-610px;}
```

Comment: Thanks, i apologies for late Reply